# Unable to start Java DB server in NetBeans 14 JDK 18.0.2.1 (MAC)

Tags: java, database, macos, netbeans

I've attempted solutions posted on similar questions but have been unable to resolve my issue. I am trying to create a Java DB through NetBeans however when pressing "Create Database" after right-clicking Java DB, the IDE continuously says "Starting the Java DB Server" as shown in the following image: [Starting Java DB Server in the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmot.png)

I have attempted an approach using GlassFish as a server and have tried moving derby to diffrent recommended directories. I've been at this for hours so any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question without comment because it is _"Not about programming or software development"_ please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) This question is very much about _"software development"_, clearly relates to _"software tools commonly used by programmers"_, and is _"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_. You should withdraw your close vote.

Comment: Your environment is invalid because you are running NetBeans 14 with JDK 8. [From the NetBeans 14 release notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb14/nb14.html): _"The Apache NetBeans 14 binary releases **require JDK 11+**"_. To use JDK 1.8 you need to downgrade to NetBeans 12.5 or earlier. Otherwise upgrade your JDK to >= JDK 11. After you have fixed your environment, update your question if the problem persists.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you so much for your response - I was completely unaware that I should consider upgrading my JDK. I have updated to JDK 18 now but the problem is still exactly the same.

Comment: [1] What is the exact version of GlassFish that you are running? You will see a message specifying the version near the start of the GlassFish log. In my case it states _"Running GlassFish Version: Eclipse GlassFish  6.1.0"_. That matters. For example, version 6.1.0 only supports JDK11,  but version 6.2.0 supports JDK 17, and I don't think you can use Glassfish with JDK 18 yet. [2] Is Glassfish running OK? If it is you should be able to connect to it using `http://localhost:8080`. [3] Make sure you can run Glassfish, and connect to it, before worrying about Java DB.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: you can use Glassfish releases 6.2.4 and 6.2.5 with _"JDK 18-EA releases"_. So presumably the formal release of JDK18 is also supported, though I don't see that explicitly stated anywhere. See https://glassfish.org/ for details.

Comment: [1] I'm using NB 15/Java 18/GlassFish 6.2.5, and also have problems with Derby, though I don't get your error. Instead, I get the problem described in this unresolved NetBeans Bug: [Unable to use Derby DB version 10.15.1.3 in Netbeans 11.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3424). [2] Can you at least start and stop the Java DB server successfully?